# JWT hs512 signature slightly different from jwt.io if calculated with python

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, base64, signature, hmac

So I get different signatures for the same JWT.

**Header**:

```js
{
  "alg": "HS512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**Payload**:

```js
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

as a signing key I used "**abc**"

The resulting JWT from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) is the following:    `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.sNgS2IRq0LCvUaIzg9dCBVvmY_9KnrXDEmKTii6U4APbRMeUkU084wf3h5v4baP2WeZOyGunCTEa9wxh25IW6w`

if I calculate the signature with python like this:

```python
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

s= b"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ"

res = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(b"abc", msg=s, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).digest())

print(res)
```

then this is printed:
`b'sNgS2IRq0LCvUaIzg9dCBVvmY/9KnrXDEmKTii6U4APbRMeUkU084wf3h5v4baP2WeZOyGunCTEa9wxh25IW6w=='`

Now except for the last two characters "==" and this "/" they are identical. Can someone explain to me why that is the case? Is it just the padding of the base64 and practically it doesn't matter if the two equal signs are there or not? Is that why jwt.io removes them?

EDIT:
Changing the python code accoding to jps' hint does the trick:

```python
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

s= b"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ"

res = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(b"abc", msg=s, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).digest())
x = res.decode("utf-8")
x = x.replace("+","-")
x = x.replace("/","_")
x = x.replace("=", "")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Python code you used Base64 encoding, but the [JWT standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3) requires [Base64URL](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) encoding. The differences are that the characters "+" and "/" in Base64 encoding are replaced with "-"  and "_" and that padding is omitted.

It might or might not work, depending on the receiving sides Base64URL decoder implementation. To be on the safe side, I recommend to follow the standard.

Comment: So  adding 

x = res.decode("utf-8")
x = x.replace("+","-")
x = x.replace("/","_")
x = x.replace("=", "")

Should always fix the problem right ?!

Comment: Does jwt standard explicitly disallow padding? The linked rfc7519 doesn't state padding `==` is disallowed.

Comment: @TheMaster padding is not mentioned at all in the RFC, but it mentions that "Each part contains a base64url-encoded  value", and base64url doesn't use padding, because a "=" in a url has a special meaning.

Comment: @jps Checking again, It seems it's left to implementation. I don't think jwt will fail due to extra padding.

Comment: @TheMaster I also don't think that a normal JWT framework would have problems with padding on the hash, and in most cases the JWT is not transmitted in the URL but in the HTTP header. But there are often questions caused by the nuances of the different Base64 encoding standards and when in doubt I can only recommend to follow the standard to be on the safe side.